# Iterating through a hsv image keeps crashin

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to iterate through a HSV image but It keeps crashing.

```
   Mat a=imread("play.jpg");
   Mat hsvimage, hsvimage2,cont;
   cvtColor(a, hsvimage, CV_BGR2HSV );
   imshow("image",a);
   inRange(hsvimage, Scalar(20, 100, 100), Scalar(170, 255, 255),hsvimage2);
   imshow("Thresholded image",hsvimage2);

      for(int i=0; i<hsvimage2.rows; i++)
       for(int j=0; i<hsvimage2.cols; j++)
  //the line belows keeps failing
 std::cout <<hsvimage2.at<uchar>(i,j) << " " << hsvimage2.at<uchar>(i,j) << " " << hsvimage2.at<uchar>(i,j) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possibly crashing because you have a typo in the inner loop, where you compare with `i` instead of `j` in the termination condition.

```
for(int j=0; i<hsvimage2.cols; j++)
```

Also, if you have a BGR image going in (3 channels), you'll get a HSV image out (3 channels), but you are accessing the pixels as if they were single channel. Try something like this for your loop to dump the H, S and V values:

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<hsvimage2.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<hsvimage2.cols; j++)   // original error was on this line
    { 
        Vec3b pHSV = hsvimage2.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
        std::cout << pHSV.val[0] << " " 
                  << pHSV.val[1] << " " 
                  << pHSV.val[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```